# Video doorbell PCB connectors

Tags: identification, connector

I have a video doorbell system with a faulty power connector, 2pin.

Can you identify these connectors?
The pitch is about 2mm.

[image]

Comment: Please, no "about". Measure distance between several pins and divide it, that way you will also divide your measurement error, so it will be clear what exactly the pitch is, namely 2mm or 2.54mm. I suggest you go to mouser or digikey, they have a lot of similar connectors

Comment: Pretty sure it's a connector from Molex or JST, maybe PH serie for example
https://www.jst.fr/fr/produit/ph_159
Do you have the exact pitch ? And other photos ?

Comment: (To get the most accurate pitch measurement, measure distance between the four pins, and divide by three [generally pitch = distance / (npins - 1)]).

Comment: Unrelated to the question, the crimp job on the black cable is horrible and likely the reason for any problems you are having.

Answer (score 0):

It is manufacturer JST, PH family of 2.0mm pitch connectors. Part number for top entry through-hole 4 pin should be B4B-PH-K-S. In case they are SMD (your pic is too bad to tell), then it is B4B-PH-SM4-TB instead.

https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=199

Answer (score 0):

I used this [Connector Identification Utility](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=interior_rect_conn&u=wire_to_board_conn&o=discrete_1row_w2b_conn&f=discrete_1row_w2b_conn_2&s=WR-WTB%20620) to identity them as Wurth WR-WTB 620 connectors. Part number 620304124022 [Digikey page](https://www.digikey.se/product-detail/en/w%C3%BCrth-elektronik/620304124022/732-2709-2-ND/2508478).

"Disclosure: I created and run the Connector Identification Utility website linked in this answer"